# Can one core on a multicore linux system be dedicated to one user-space app?

Tags: linux, cpu, gpio

Can a core be dedicated to one user-space app (e.g. for the purpose of bit-banging GPIO without *any* interruptions)?

Comment: If you don't get a timely answer here, you could start looking into `cgroups`, I think specifically the `cpuset` parameter; see [e.g. here](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2014/11/04/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups) (scroll down to the "cgroups" section).   Hopefully excluding everything but a specific group from a specific core is not too convoluted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the kernel `isolcpus` option in conjunction with the `taskset` command.

On the Raspberry Pi reserve the core(s) you want to use by appending the following to the line in `/boot/cmdline.txt`.

E.g. to reserve cores 2 and 3.

```
isolcpus=2,3
```

Then use taskset to assign programs to the core(s).

E.g. to launch the Python interpreter.

```
taskset -c 3 python
```

(look [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html) for information on how to use the command).

If this is Raspberry Pi specific do you need to bit bang?  There may be already existing solutions.